# How to ignore new lines while reading blocks of data from file

Tags: c++

Im trying to [read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) blocks of data from a file, but I couldn't know how to ignore the newline character when I use istream::read.

Im aware that I can use for loop to load the characters to a cstring one by one with condition to ignore new lines character, but I hope there is clever way to solve this problem.

My intention to avoid using strings or vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

void readIt(char* fileName) {
    std::ifstream seqsFile;
    seqsFile.open(fileName) ;

    if (seqsFile.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Failed in opening: " << fileName << std::endl;
        std::exit(1);
    }
    seqsFile.seekg(84);
    char *buffer;
    buffer = new char [7];
    seqsFile.read(buffer, 7);
    buffer[7] = 0;
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}    

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    readIt(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

file:

```
gsi|33112219|sp|O
GACATTCTGGTGGTGGACTCGGAGGCATGATAGCAGGTGCAGCTGGTGCAGCCGCAGCAGCTTATGGAGC
GCAGCAGCTTATGGAGC
```

current output:

GAGC

GC

desired output: 
GAGCGCA

modified version:

```
void readIt(char* fileName) {
    std::ifstream seqsFile;
    seqsFile.open(fileName) ;

    if (seqsFile.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Failed in opening: " << fileName << std::endl;
        std::exit(1);
    }
    seqsFile.seekg(84);
    char *buffer;
    buffer = new char [7];
    char next ;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 7; i++) {
        seqsFile.get(next);
        if (next=='\n') {
            i--;
            continue;
        }   
        buffer[i] = next;
    }

    buffer[7]=0;
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Are your blocks always of 7 letters?

Comment: yes, K-mers of length 7

Comment: No, there's no clever way. You have to loop one way or another. While you're at it, ditch `new` and `char*` and use `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has undefined behavior since you are modifying `buffer` using an out of range index. You have:

```
buffer = new char [7];      // Allocating 7 chars.
seqsFile.read(buffer, 7);   // Reading 7 chars. OK.
buffer[7] = 0;              // 7 is an out of range index. Not OK.
```

Allocate memory for at least 8 `char`s.

```
buffer = new char [8];
```

Also, when you intend to read the contents of a file using `istream::read`, it is recommended that you open the file in binary mode.

```
seqsFile.open(fileName, std::ios_base::binary) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can not tell not to *read* newlines - they will appear in your buffer variable anyway and you have to handle it.
Also, you have to fix the buffer size, as R Sahu mentioned

Regarding your question, i can suggest following snippet:

```
while ((index = strlen(buffer)) < 7)
{
  seqsFile >> &buffer[index];
}
```

strlen here will return size of buffer upto /0 or newline character as well
You didn't tell what to do with whitespaces, so they will be ignored as well